# Safe way to resolve dependency conflict for Drive and Dropbox?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I would like to integrate my app with a variety of file storage services.  I followed the quickstart instructions for the Drive sdk, which adds a bunch of jars to my projects libs directory.  Additionally, the Dropbox sdk requires the following list of jars:

- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3.jar
- httpclient-4.0.3.jar
- httpcore-4.0.1.jar
- httpmime-4.0.3.jar
- json-simple-1.1.jar

Once all of these are added to my project, I get the following error when I try to run:

> Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define
>   Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;

If I remove the httpmime jar added for Dropbox, my project runs fine.  But is this a safe way to resolve the conflict?  Is there an alternative method with which I can build my project and include all the required jars?

Comment: Is httpmine jarfile in the other SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no version conflicts this would work fine. Compare the httpmime-4.0.3.jar to the httpmime jar that Drive added to your libs directory. If they're the same, then it's fine. If they're different, then you'll have to find out the differences between the two and insure that they're not breaking changes. As a last resort you could also repackage one of the SDKs with its required version of httpmime in a jar selectively obfuscated with ProGuard, though that's a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing with Eclipse, consider using Google Plugin for Eclipse. It provides a way to add any of the Google's SDK to your app. All the jars are added automatically.